# HTML not showing results

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a calculator and having an issue. The Calculations are not showing up. I'm thinking I have something to do with "**Total:**  **Test:**" Not sure if that is the issue or somewhere in the code. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Calc</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calculateTotal').click(function() {

        var inputNum_of_Emp = $('#emp').val();

        var Total_Formula = Math.pow(inputNum_of_Emp, -.2498);

        var totalCost = (9.94 * Total_Formula);

        var nettotalCost = totalcost * inputNum_of_Emp

        $('#total').html(formatCurrency(totalCost));
        $('#net').html(formatCurrency(nettotalCost));
        $('#result').css('display', 'block');
      });
    });
     // This Function I have searched from Web 
    function formatCurrency(strValue) {
      strValue = strValue.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
      dblValue = parseFloat(strValue);

      blnSign = (dblValue == (dblValue = Math.abs(dblValue)));
      dblValue = Math.floor(dblValue * 100 + 0.50000000001);
      intCents = dblValue % 100;
      strCents = intCents.toString();
      dblValue = Math.floor(dblValue / 100).toString();
      if (intCents < 10)
        strCents = "0" + strCents;
      for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((dblValue.length - (1 + i)) / 3); i++)
        dblValue = dblValue.substring(0, dblValue.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' +
        dblValue.substring(dblValue.length - (4 * i + 3));
      return (((blnSign) ? '' : '-') + '$' + dblValue + '.' + strCents);
    }

    -- >
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="calc" name="calc">
    <p>
      <label for="emp">Number Of Employees</label>
      <input id="emp" name="empnumber" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input name="calculateTotal" id="calculateTotal" type="button" value="Calculate Total" />
    </p>
    <div id="result" style="display:none;"><strong>Total:</strong>  <span id="total"></span><strong>Test:</strong><span id="net"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: my answer works. i have tested it too. if you find it helpful and correct please mark my answer as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u see the simple c instead of Capital C

```
var nettotalCost = totalCost * inputNum_of_Emp;
```

Look at the code you provided.  With this change code works fine. Tested

```
$('#calculateTotal').click(function() {
      //alert("ok here");

        var inputNum_of_Emp = $('#emp').val();
      //alert(inputNum_of_Emp);
        var Total_Formula = Math.pow(inputNum_of_Emp, -.2498);
      //alert(Total_Formula);
        var totalCost = (9.94 * Total_Formula);
      //alert(totalCost);
        var nettotalCost = totalCost * inputNum_of_Emp;
      //Error: var nettotalCost = totalcost * inputNum_of_Emp  simple c
      //instead of uppercase C in totalCost
      //alert(nettotalCost); //now works fine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#total').html(formatCurrency(totalCost));
 $('#net').html(formatCurrency(nettotalCost));
```

I suggest you to use .append instead of .html function.